# Can a community be created without using public Site?

Tags: community

Currently We've created a force.com site and 
and community. Force.com site has static pages, which 
are visible to unautheticated user.To Register/login we are redirecting  the user 
to community. Once the user is logged in and autheticated successfully for community,
he will be able to see the pages in community.

But Instead of using both force.com site and comunity.
Can I use only community? Means can i create my website(static pages) in community.

Static pages in community can be visible  to unauthticated user and once user logged in,
autheticated pages should be visible to them . Can I Create this functionality in my
Community.

Comment: You can have community pages available to the guest user profile for the community (public). And pages available after a login process tied to a different profile tied to the community (authenticated), and block the guest user profiles access to those pages.